# Smooth Div Scroll - Scroll Right resets on mouse off

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, smoothing, smooth-scrolling

I'm having  few issues with the jquery plugin smoothdivscroll.

Essentially, I'm trying to get the plugin to run as this page: http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/demo.html

However, I have changes the javascript, as is needs to scroll automatically but allow the hotspots to work as well, but revert to auto scroll on the mouse leaving the hotspot.

While the code below works, after yout have left the trigger on the right, it 'resets' back to the first div.

Is there any way to set it to resume scrolling from the set position?

code:

```
    // Initialize the plugin with no custom options
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // I just set some of the options
        $("div#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
        mousewheelScrolling: true,
        visibleHotSpotBackgrounds: "always",
        autoScrollingMode: "endlessright"
        });


    });
    //This is just to make the scroller pause...
    $("#makeMeScrollable").bind("mouseover", function() {
    $(this).smoothDivScroll("stopAutoScrolling");
    }).bind("mouseout", function() {
    $(this).smoothDivScroll("startAutoScrolling");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is what causes your problems, but you need to pay attention to the parenthesis. Change the code to this:

```
// jQuery document ready
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Initialize the scroller
  $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
    mousewheelScrolling: true,
    visibleHotSpotBackgrounds: "always",
    autoScrollingMode: "endlessright"
  });

  //This is just to make the scroller pause...
  $("#makeMeScrollable").bind("mouseover", function() {
    $(this).smoothDivScroll("stopAutoScrolling");
    }).bind("mouseout", function() {
    $(this).smoothDivScroll("startAutoScrolling");
  });
}); // End query document ready
```

I haven't tested this code, but unless I made a typo it's the correct way to do it.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, it still goes crazy resetting to the 1st div again. but tidy syntax is always good.

Comment: I'm curious to see this in case it's a bug that has to be addressed. Do you have a URL to a test page?

Comment: http://www.vettacreative.co.uk/scroll/ if you use the hotspots on the left an right as well, you'll see what I mean. Thanks

Comment: Yes - I can reproduce this behavior, not only in IE (7,8,9) but also in the latest version of Chrome. So something weird happens when you combine autoscrolling and manual scrolling in this way.

Comment: That's what I mean, is it just not meant to be having both?

Comment: James: No, it was originally intended to scroll content manually (no autoscrolling). But as its popularity grew there was a great demand for autoscrolling so I added it. Now it seems that many people want both - autoscrolling which disabled if the user interacts with the scroller and activated again if the user stops interacting with the scroller.

Answer (score 0):

I saw that the options are not right. Try this (if you are using the latest version, which is version 1.2):

```
  // Initialize the scroller
  $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
    mousewheelScrolling: true,
    visibleHotSpotBackgrounds: "always",
    autoScrollingMode: "onstart",
    autoScrollingDirection: "endlessloopright",
    manualContinuousScrolling: true
  });
```

In this configuration the scroller will be autoscrolling in an ensless loop right when it loads. As soon as the user uses the mousewheel or the hotspots, autoscrolling will stop and if not for your custom eventhandlers it would not start autoscrolling again. But since you have them, it should start again as soon as the user leaves the scollable area.

I've also set manualContinuousScrolling to true so you get the same endless looping when scrolling manually.

This has not been tested so you might have to do some adjustments. For example I'm not sure if autoScrollingMode: "onstart" or autoScrollingMode: "always" is the best choice. You'll just have to try.

Answer (score 0):

I believe also important that maybe different versions will affect behaviour. 
This worked for my: jquery.smoothDivScroll-1.1-min.js version.

Note the difference of the function names: stopAutoScroll vs. stopAutoScrolling etc.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({ 
        autoScroll: "always", 
        autoScrollDirection: "backandforth", 
        autoScrollStep: 1, 
        autoScrollInterval: 25, 
        startAtElementId: "startAtMe"
    });

    //This is just to make the scroller pause...
    $("#makeMeScrollable").bind("mouseover", function() {
        $(this).smoothDivScroll("stopAutoScroll");
        }).bind("mouseout", function() {
        $(this).smoothDivScroll("startAutoScroll");
    });
});
```